# TypeError: #<Promise> is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, promise

i tried 3 days ago for read image from backend and this best solution i'm tried but i got error and don't understand the error

please help

```
  get_image:(req,res)=>{
const directoryPath = __basedir + "/uploads/";
const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/test/get_image/";
fs.readdir(directoryPath,  function (err, files) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Unable to scan files!",
    });
  }
  let fileInfos = [];
  files.forEach(Image.findAll().then(data=>{   <<=== error here 
    fileInfos.push({
      name: data.name,
      url:  baseUrl+data.name,
    });
  }))
})
   }
```

Error :

```
 files.forEach(Image.findAll().then(data=>{
        ^
TypeError: #<Promise> is not a function
```

Comment: `.forEach( foo )` expects `foo` to be a function that will be executed for each element. However in your case  `foo = Image.findAll().then( /* ... */ )` which is a promise, not a function.

Comment: You have passed a `Promise` to `files.forEach(...)` instead of a callback function.

Comment: same problem :  files.forEach(foo) =>TypeError: #<Promise> is not a function

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to explain... you cannot pass a promise to `forEach`. And I don't know what you're attempting to do, so I can't tell you what the correct code is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
  get_image: (req, res) => {
    const directoryPath = __basedir + "/uploads/";
    const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/test/get_image/";
    fs.readdir(directoryPath, async function(err, files) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: "Unable to scan files!"
        });
      }
      let data = await Image.findAll();
      let fileInfos = files.map(file => ({
        name: data.name,
        url: baseUrl + data.name
      }));
    });
  }
```

Instead of iteration over and over again you could fetch data once and then map it

Comment: T_T no data 

   {
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/test/get_image/undefined"
    }

it should by  {
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/test/get_image/data.name"
    }

Comment: @yaserOtakU well `Image.findAll()` resolves undefined for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code block

```js
files.forEach(Image.findAll().then(data=>{   <<=== error here 
    fileInfos.push({
      name: data.name,
      url:  baseUrl+data.name,
    });
  }))
```

to

```
const responseList = await Promise.all(
    files.map(() => {
        return Image.findAll().then(data => {
            return fileInfos.push({
                name: data.name,
                url: baseUrl + data.name,
            });
        })
    })
)
```

Then it will work. I have used Promise.all to run all the request in parallel

Comment: `responseList` will be undefined

Comment: `files.forEach(...)` will return undefined to `Promise.all(...)` and that is what the value of `responseList` will be. You can't return anything from `.forEach()` method.

Comment: @Ifaruki Thanks made the correction. Actually I didn't write it in IDE that's why made the mistake